# rdlc in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I would like to create a **rdlc** report at run time. I don't want to fix the columns because my query changes each time.  Also, I would like to set the report layout at run time.  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You are going to have to post some more details for anyone to be able to help. 
PS. go easy on .....

Answer (score 0):

This is the schema on how I programmed the visibility of the columns in my reports:

- Create a tabular report with all the colums
- Add a function in the report code section, the name could be IsHidden(String ColumnName)
- Change the visibility of every column to =IsHidden("YourColumnName"), ColumnName needs to change every column

When executing the report:

- Read the report inside an xml document
- analyze the RDLC, get all the nodes with the isHidden function, replace it with True or False depending on what columns you need to show or hide.

You can select all the nodes containing the IsHidden function using this snippet:

`System.Xml.XmlNodeList TableColunmnList = xmldoc.SelectNodes("rs:Report//*/rs:Visibility[rs:Hidden='=Code.IsHidden(\"" + FieldName + "\")']", xmlnsManager)`;

- reload the RDL code using this code, XmlReport is the RDL code

`System.IO.TextReader reader = new System.IO.StringReader(XmlReport);
reportViewer1.Reset();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(reader);`

- That's all, your report has dynamic visibility on all the columns.